# SHS module in drupal 7 views

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-exposed-filter

Am using Simple hierarchical select module and am having terms lists like below;

**India**
- Karnataka
-- Bangalore

So, I want this filed as exposed filter in my views. Let me give example, assume if 3 nodes are selected "Bangalore".

So, whenever I select the "India" or "Karnataka" means it should shows the content which is selected as "Bangalore" in views.

How should I achieve this process?

Can anyone please help me out in this case?

Thanks in advance